# How to get grunt-watch to live reload HTML changes under different build tasks

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I can easily set up my Grunt file to live reload HTML and SCSS changes by doing something like:

```
watch: {
    options: {
        livereload: true,
    },
    css: {
        files: ['scss/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['compass']
    },
    html: {
        files: ['index.html'],
        tasks: ['build']
    }
}
```

However, I have a build task for dev environment: `dev`, and a build task for production environment: `build`. Therefore, calling `build` when the HTML is changed will build the site for production which is not what I want if I only want the dev version.

Ideally I would do something like:

```
watch: {
    options: {
        livereload: true,
    },

    dev: {
        html: {
            files: ['<%%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
                    '<%%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.html'],
            tasks: ['dev']
        },

        css: {
            files: ['<%%= yeoman.app %>/assets/scss/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['compass']
        }
    },

    dist: {
        html: {
            files: ['<%%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
                    '<%%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.html'],
            tasks: ['build']
        },

        css: {
            files: ['<%%= yeoman.app %>/assets/scss/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['compass'],
        }
    }
}
```

Thereby being able to call `watch:dev` or `watch:dist`, however this code does not work.

The only work-around I can figure out is to have:

```
…
    dev: {
        files: ['<%%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
                '<%%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.html',
                '<%%= yeoman.app %>/assets/scss/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['dev']
    },

    dist: {
        files: ['<%%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
                '<%%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.html',
                '<%%= yeoman.app %>/assets/scss/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['build']
    }
…
```

Again calling `watch:dev` or `watch:dist`, but the downside to this is that I don't want to be rebuilding the whole site when I'm just changing a small amount of SCSS.

Is there any way to achieve what I am after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a dynamic alias task:

```
grunt.registerTask('watchit', function(type) {
  grunt.config('watch.html.tasks', type);
  grunt.task.run('watch');
});
```

Then call it with `grunt watchit:build` or `grunt watchit:dev` to switch between the two.

More info here: http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#dynamic-alias-tasks

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I hadn't made the connection that it was a dynamic task that was needed in this situation.